# MYSQL where or statement not working as expected

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I'm trying to count the number of rows in this query, however it's not working as expected, this returns an extra row, it should be 12, but it's 13.

```
$numPhotos = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("
SELECT albums.id 
FROM albums, albumData
WHERE 
(albumData.id=albums.albumID OR albums.albumID=0)
AND
albums.userID=$id
AND albums.state=0
AND albumData.state=0
"));
```

When I remove the OR statement part, and not count the rows with albumID=0, it returns 11. There is only one row where the albumID is 0, but it counts it as two?

```
$numPhotos = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("
SELECT albums.id 
FROM albums, albumData
WHERE 
albumData.id=albums.albumID
AND
albums.userID=$id
AND albums.state=0
AND albumData.state=0
"));
```

Comment: What happens if instead of counting the rows returned, you actually display them? That should show you what it's actually returning, and let you see the mysterious extra row that shows up when you add the OR clause.

(if you don't want to mess with your PHP code, you could just drop the query into the mysql command line. It looks like it should work fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write query using JOIN:

```
SELECT albums.id FROM albums
LEFT JOIN albumData 
   ON albums.albumID=albumData.id
  AND albums.state=0
  AND albumData.state=0
WHERE albums.userID=$id
```

or

```
SELECT albums.id FROM albums
LEFT JOIN albumData 
   ON albums.albumID=albumData.id
WHERE albums.userID=$id
  AND albums.state=0
  AND albumData.state=0
```

Does this solve your trouble?

**EDITED:**
Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT albums.id FROM albums
INNER JOIN albumData 
   ON (albums.albumID = albumData.id OR albums.albumID = 0)
  AND albums.state=0
  AND albumData.state=0
WHERE albums.userID=$id
```

Comment: neither do, those aren't counting where albums.albumID=0, as it should. (albums.albumID=0 is not in albumData, as with all of the other albumIDs are) albumID=0 is just in albums table, it is a default for each user (to define a specific album, in my case, profile photo album)

Comment: It's still returning 11 as before, it doesn't count the albumID=0, which it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your query columns with count(*), like this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM albums, albumData
WHERE 
(albumData.id=albums.albumID OR albums.albumID=0)
AND
albums.userID=$id
AND albums.state=0
AND albumData.state=0
```

This query will return one row & column and it will contain the number of rows generated by the query.